# Digital simulation display

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I am new in the field of electronic circuit simulation and the two articles i am reading from

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_circuit_simulation
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE

have led me to ask this question.Supposing i am running an analog and digital simulator like LTSpice analog and digital simulator,can i have an LED display inside the LTSpice analog and digital simulator to display some data for instance if i am working on a data acquisition circuit?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LTspice you won't have any way to display data except for waveform plots - which is what you're going to use most of the time for analog circuit design.

You won't see a LED blink or a 7-segment display, if that is what you're looking for. There are other simulators that can do that (e.g. Multisim, Proteus), but I find those features to be of limited use at best.

You could, however, export the data to a text file and then use other software to process it - that includes visualizing it in other way you might want to.

Comment: Why are those features of limited use?. Give me at least one reason why.Thanks.

Comment: In my digital work (that is, using LEDs, 7-seg displays, LCDs etc...) I tend to use microcontrollers which aren't simulated properly by circuit simulators (even if they're supported, the simulation often is slow and doesn't behave like a real circuit would). But then, your needs might vary.